# Invalid key hash while integrating Facebook login

Tags: java, android, facebook

I am using Facebook `LoginManager` class to integrate Facebook login in my app. So when I install my app first time and try to login everything works fine and I can easily get the access token using `loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()`.

But once I uninstall & re-install my app and try to login again, it throws me an `Facebook Exception` **"Invalid key hash. The key hash NDMi5aisFkTeU6BlER3L8JZ+wHw= does not match any stored key hashes. Configure your app key hashes at http://developers.facebook.com/apps/1646433015643090"**

So why this, Is anything to do while uninstalling the app.

**Code I used**

```
FacebookSdk.sdkInitialize(getApplicationContext());
mCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

        LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions((Activity)mContext, Arrays.asList("email", "user_photos", "public_profile"));

        LoginManager.getInstance().registerCallback(mCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult)
            {
                new FacebookLoginLoaderTask(mContext, loginResult.getAccessToken().getToken()).executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.SERIAL_EXECUTOR);

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancel()
            {
                System.out.print("Login Cancel");
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(FacebookException exception)
            {

            }
        });
```

Comment: is your app is in development mode or open for public?

Comment: Devlopment mode..How can I make it public?

Comment: i am uploading answer for this. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write below code in onCreate method :

```
try {
            PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                    "your package name", PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
            for (android.content.pm.Signature signature : info.signatures) {
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
                md.update(signature.toByteArray());
                String sign = Base64
                        .encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT);

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), sign, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }

        } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

        }
```

Debug your app. copy the `sign` code .

```
After that go to your facebook app -> go to settings -> paste this key hashes over there  after that make tab to yes for `Single Sign On` and saved it.
```

Now go to `status & Review -> make make it public` .

Its done. !!

Comment: One more thing.,Right now I have set my release key store value in Facebook developer console. Is it fine or I need to used debug.keystore value.

Comment: At first time when you set up your app then use degub.keystore value. After that go to settings and paste this new keyhashes value. 
There are two keys `1) Development Key Hashes - set your degub.keystore value.
2) Release Key Hash - set this value which  you get from the above code`

Comment: Yep its working..:) thanks, bye the way I want to know why they don't do the same thing with our release keystore value, Instead the send their keyhash value and again we need to replace in the console.

Comment: Thanks. Read this `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started#release-key-hash` and  `https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/getting-started` (Create a Development Key Hash).

Answer (score 0):

In your activity's `onCreate`, use this code:

```
try {
        PackageInfo info = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(
                "com.facebook.samples.hellofacebook", 
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES);
        for (Signature signature : info.signatures) {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA");
            md.update(signature.toByteArray());
            Log.d("KeyHash:", Base64.encodeToString(md.digest(), Base64.DEFAULT));
            }
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {

    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {

    }
```

You will see some similar to this: `12-20 10:47:37.747: D/KeyHash:(936): 478uEnKQV+fMQT8Dy4AKvHkYibo=`

Copy everything after the `D/KeyHash:(936):` in the facebook developer console and you are good to go.

After that, you can delete this snippet from your onCreate.