# Can't login with Facebook button in the app?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

My android app is released to `Closed testing` in `Alpha release` environment. To `Login with Facebook`. I followed:

1. Entered Policy URL
2. Meet all requirements
3. I can see `Your app is currently live and available to the public.`

Everything works fine for `ios` environment because we do not need to provide the `HashKey` (I guess so).

For Android, I am able to login from Facebook web view (`When user don't have installed Facebook application in their mobile`) but it's throwing `Error connecting to Facebook` in case of Facebook app is installed.

To generate the HashKey:

```
keytool -exportcert -alias fbrelease -keystore release.jks | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64
```

where alias is `fbrelease` and `keystore path` is also correct. I am using the same `Kyestore` using for generating the `signed APK`
Am I missing something here?

Comment: This will help you - https://stackoverflow.com/a/31785713/3774906

Comment: @rushankshah I think this is for putting debug hash key. right?

Comment: Yes from that code you will get hash key . In your case problem is with hash key only.

Comment: Let me try it ..

Comment: You can also do 1 thing , run your signed apk on device and attach that device to android studio . When you will get error on facebook login then you can view the hash key with error message in error log. !!! Copy that hash key and paste to fb devs console.

Comment: @rushankshah I tried and nothing changed. I can't see any information even in the Log. I took the hash and paste it to facebook developer account. When I clicks on "Login" button. I can the spinner but it resumes the activity again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/150165/discussion-between-rushank-shah-and-komal-sharma).

Comment: one more thing: I am getting this popup "your package name" is not found in play store. is it something to do with this error?

Comment: No you can ignore this error

Comment: @rushankshah just figure it out. It was an issue of multiple instance of login from the native app. I called ` LoginManager.getInstance().logOut();` and it works. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Ok. Great !!!!!